# How to run a somethingHere.java with Netbeans using the Class ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want to run the NewCl.java that is a class of my current package, but i cant figure it out how to do that.I serch a lot and find a way in Eclipse but i want to do it in Netbeans. What is wrong with this code?

`String [] command = {"java","-cp",".\\build\\classes","NewCl",String.valueOf(num2),String.valueOf(num1)};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        System.out.println();
        Process p = null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i just find the solution. If someone  needs it this is the solution:

`String [] command = {"java",
                             "-cp",
                             System.getProperty("java.class.path"), 
                             "testing.NewCl", /*packagename + class*/
                             String.valueOf(num2),/*Useless for you*/
                             String.valueOf(num1)}; /*Useless for you*/`